# Redux App Structure - Where to place services / business logic?

Tags: javascript, redux, directory-structure

I'm writing my first Redux app and doing the initial rounds like choosing the boilerplate and understanding its structure. I've found a very good one called [react-redux-starter-kit](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit).

I'll need to write a notification client, fed by an API (in every X minutes it queries the API for notifications - it might be replaced by a websocket solution later). It won't have route specific visibility - it'll be always seen in the header bar. Considering the starter kit above, where would be the best to place its codebase? I'm coming from a Symfony2 world and I'd put the business logic in a class called `Notification` into a `src/services` folder:

```
.
├── src
|  ├── components/Notification - UI
|  ├── ...
|  ├── services/Notification - Business logic - there is no services folder in the starter kit, so I'm not sure about this ..
|  ├── ...
```

I'll need actions, a store and a reducer for the Notification stuff, but really unsure where to place them.
Any idea? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Based on the `src/routes/<name of route component>/modules` pattern I guess the best would be to place the application-wide logic into a `src/modules/Notification` file. Moreover if the codebase got too fatty it could be split into files like `Actions`, `Reducers` under a `src/modules/Notification` foler ...

```
.
├── src
|  ├── components/Notification - UI
|  ├── ...
|  ├── modules
|  |  ├── Notification - Business logic
|  |  |  ├── actions.js
|  |  |  ├── reducers.js
|  |  |  ├── ...
|  ├── ...
```

**UPDATE:** I've found a really good [article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/scaling-your-redux-app-with-ducks-6115955638be) about structuring our React Redux app. It walks the reader through different approaches and dilemmas, then gives and answer too.

Comment: I really recommend you to not starting with a redux app boilerplate, this is a common shortcut and mistake for beginners. Here's an example of using problems that you can encouter by using boilerplates. https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1681#issuecomment-216508641 I can't advise you more than gradually adding library that you need. And concerning your file structure, focus on your coding instead of loosing time on file structure, use the structure that makes more sense to you.

Comment: I don't really get it .. This starter kit looks solid and I'd like to understand its philosophy ..

Comment: I don't doubt that this starter kit is solid. But it is composed of a lot of libraries. Moreover, I think it is targeted to dev that are familiar with redux. I am aware that the React ecosystem offers a lot of tools to choose for your app, and it is hard to make a choice. IMHO, you will have a deeper understanding of your app and it will be easier to debug if you learn each block one by one. From the author of Redux : https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/727471253276254208?lang=en

Comment: Thanks for warning me, I'm aware of there are plenty of tools in the JS world. In the past 4-5 months I've been working (among others adding pre-rendering feature to an originally client-only) on a JS app (gulp, browserify, handlebars js ..) so I know what you mean... But this starter kit is working fantastic so far and I want to write my code the way its authors would do.

Answer (score 3):

First: boilerplates/starter kits *can* be useful, but per the comments, also confusing.  The davezuko kit is pretty good, although it's definitely become more complex over time.  If it helps, I have a [list of some suggested starter kits](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/boilerplates-and-starter-kits.md) in my [React/Redux links list](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links).  I particularly recommend [tsaiDavid/simple-redux-boilerplate](https://github.com/tsaiDavid/simple-redux-boilerplate) and [cesarandreu/web-app](https://github.com/cesarandreu/web-app) as simpler kits with great documentation.

Second: persistent logic that needs to be able to do things like API calls usually goes into a Redux middleware or a connected React component.  My [Redux addons catalog](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links) has a list of [socket and service adapter middlewares](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/middleware.md#sockets-and-adapters), some of which may be useful for you as-is, or serve as examples.

Finally, you may also want to read through the Redux FAQ question on [handling "business logic" in Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#structure-business-logic).

Answer (score 0):

As for the app structure I would suggest you to follow [this guide](http://marmelab.com/blog/2015/12/17/react-directory-structure.html)

It explains well the problem of struturing your app with component/container/actions/... folders.

As for a starter kit, I use the modified version of [react-slingshot](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot) which does a lot of heavy lifting for you. As said in the comments, it's your responsability to understand how it works in order to be able to debug it if needed.